# Is array.push a form of reassignment?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, ecmascript-6, lint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm working in a project with several javascript files and part of what I'm doing right now is both migrating existing code to use newer ES6+ features as well as making sure we're abiding by the [AirBnB Eslint Rules](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb).

So, given that context, this is the specific situation:

```
let meta = [a.platform];
```

And right below that:

```
meta.push(a.browserName ? a.browserName : 'any');
```

So now the linter is giving me a warning: **'meta is never reassigned. Use const instead'**.

---

I understand that `meta = somethingNew` would be reassigning the variable. But in this case, isn't this variable also something different than what it used to be when it was created?

**or, to make it even more clear**

Can I use a **const** to define an array that will receive new items? If not, why?

Also, if not: why is the linter throwing a warning?

Comment: Reassignment of `Object` types (like `Array`s) just means to rebind a name with another reference (to another `Object` type). When you mutate an `Object` type as in your example, you merely change its properties, but not the underlying reference.

Comment: *"But in this case, isn't this variable also something different than what it used to be when it was created?"* No. The variable still has the same array as value. The arrays was *mutated* in the meantime, but that doesn't make it a different value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only thing you have to know is that **`const` has nothing to do with immutability**. `const` simply allows you to prevent reassignment, which means that you cannot do that:

```js
   
// OK 
const foo = '';
const bar = [];
const baz = {};

// WTF are we doing!?
foo = 'Foo';
bar = ['Bar'];
baz = {baz: 'Baz'};
```

However, in JavaScript, object values are mutable ; contrary to primitive values that are immutable. So if you put a string in a `const`, you will not be able to modify it at all, even with `String.prototype` methods (which return new strings).

```js
const str = 'Lorem ipsum';

console.log(str.slice(6)); // This is actually a new string...
console.log(str); // The original string has not been modified!
```

It is quite different with arrays or object literals, though:

```js
const arr = [];
const obj = {};

arr.push('Foo');
arr.push('Bar');

obj.foo = 'Foo';
obj.bar = 'Bar';

console.log(arr); // Modified!
console.log(obj); // Modified!
```

At this point, it should be clear: the linter shows this warning because, indeed, meta is never reassigned... A mutation is not a reassignment.

Answer (score 6):

`meta.push()` doesn't reassign the variable, it just modifies the array that the variable refers to -- it's still the same array, but with different contents. So you can use `const` for the variable declaration, since you never make it refer to a different array.

The same is true if you assign to array elements. This is OK:

```
const meta = [a.platform];
meta[1] = somethingNew;
```

The second assignment doesn't change `meta`, it changes the array.